# No module named 'bokeh.plotting'; bokeh is not a package

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to import `curdoc`. I have tried `from bokeh.io import curdoc` and `from bokeh.plotting import curdoc`but neither works.

I've tried `pip install -U bokeh` and `pip install bokeh` but it still returns `no module named 'bokeh.plotting; 'bokeh' is not a package'`. What is happening?

I have reverted back to 0.12.1 currently.

Comment: Do you have a file in the directory called `bokeh.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: that was the answer.. thanks!

Comment: @glibdud can you add that as an answer instead of a comment so that this question has a proper answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your folder if any of the program named bokeh.py please rename it because it's picking bokeh.plotting from your program bokeh.py not from the library.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the `bokeh.py` file and deleting `bokeh.pyc` file solved it for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).